# insert datagridview data to database using stored procedurein vb.net

Tags: sql-server-2012, vb.net-2010

I am was having trouble on how to insert data on my database using stored procedure. every time run my code this message appears 
  "Procedure or function 'ScheduleofFeesInsert' expects parameter '@SchoolYear', which was not supplied.".

Here is my vb code:

```
   Private Sub btnSet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSet.Click
    Dim strConn As String = "Data Source=Jansen;Initial 
      Catalog=SLCBRegistrarDB;Integrated Security=True"
    Dim sqlCon As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(strConn)
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    CMD = New SqlCommand
    CMD.Connection = sqlCon
    CMD.CommandText = "ScheduleofFeesInsert"
    CMD.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    'Save Current Fees
    sqlCon.Open()
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcademicYear", My.Settings.SchoolYear)
    CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Period", My.Settings.CurrentPeriod)
    CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@FeeID", SqlDbType.Int))
    CMD.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Amount", SqlDbType.Decimal))
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgvScheduleofFees.Rows
        If Not row.IsNewRow Then
            CMD.Parameters("@Amount").Value = row.Cells(0).Value
            CMD.Parameters("@FeeID").Value = row.Cells(1).Value
            CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    Next
    sqlCon.Close()
    End Sub
```

And Sqlserver Stored Procedure:

```
USE [SLCBRegistrarDB]
GO/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ScheduleofFeesInsert]    Script 
 Date: 7/10/2017 4:00:34 PM ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO
 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ScheduleofFeesInsert]

 @Period nvarchar(50),
 @SchoolYear nvarchar(50),
 @FeeID int,
 @Amount decimal(18,0)

 AS
 Begin
    Declare @PeriodID int
    Declare @SYID int


Select @PeriodID=SemID FROM SemesterList where Description=@Period

Select @SYID=[SY ID] FROM SchoolYear where [School Year]=@SchoolYear

INSERT INTO FEESSetup VALUES (@FeeID,@Amount,@PeriodID,@SYID)

END
```

I don't know what i'd missed. i've tried to modify my code but nothing happens. please help.

Comment: ("@AcademicYear", My.Settings.SchoolYear), change to ("@SchoolYear", My.Settings.SchoolYear)

Comment: wow! i didn't see that one.. haha thanks bro, you're a big help.

Comment: oww..apologies bro, i am just a beginner and  i'm just new with stackoverflow. kindly teach me how do i mark this question as answered. thanks man. :)

Comment: In Answer section, there are two arrow button. Up arrow and down arrow. U can vote and accept as an answer. Follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers
OR
Choose one answer that you believe is the best solution to your problem.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.
You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are passing value for school year

```
CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcademicYear", My.Settings.SchoolYear)
```

but in your stored procedure has a different parameter name for given value. change the above code to

```
CMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SchoolYear", My.Settings.SchoolYear)
```